# Android - Read a File

Tags: android, file-io, constructor, implicit, super

I am trying to read a list of exercises from a file Exercises.txt in my `/assests` folder and I've found plenty of examples how to, but I keep getting the error "context cannot be resolved" and if I manage to fix that, then I get "Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

Here is my code:

```
class ChooseExercises extends ListActivity{

    String[] exercises;

    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();  //Error 1
    InputStream inputStream = am.open("test.txt"); //Error 2
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choose_exercises);
    }

}
```

Thank you all for assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is nothing named `context`, you cannot refer to it from a data member initializer.

So, start by moving your `AssetManager` and subsequent data members into `onCreate()` as local variables, and replace `context.getAssets()` with just `getAssets()`, and you will be in better shape.

```
class ChooseExercises extends ListActivity{
    String[] exercises;

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choose_exercises);

        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();  //Error 1
        InputStream inputStream = am.open("test.txt"); //Error 2
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        // TODO: actually use this stuff
    }
}
```

Later, as you get more comfortable with Java and Android, move this disk I/O into a background thread.

Comment: What method do you recommend for reading data from a webservice? I bought you book and in it you usually read the response line by line. I didn't know if there's a forum for your book, so I asked the question here in stackoverflow http://goo.gl/9MdzpL

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to use a try-catch construction.

Writing:

```
try{
            FileOutputStream fos = getBaseContext().openFileOutput("fileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject("content");
            os.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            //do stuff if something goes wrong.
        }finally{
            //do stuff in the end.
        }
```

Reading:

```
try{
        FileInputStream fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput("filename");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object s = (Object) is.readObject(); // Object must be String if you want to read a string.
        is.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //do stuff if something goes wrong.
    }finally{
        //do stuff in the end.
    }
```

Comment: am.open("test.txt"); requires a try-catch